# Make Bottom Div Scrollable when parent Div is over X Height

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im trying to have a container div with a fixed height of 350px.Inside that div, there are 2 Sub-Divs, both with variable height.

My Goal is now, that if the 2 Sub-Divs together are bigger than the parent div, the bottom-sub-div will get a scrollbar.

The Problem now is, that whatever i try, the parent-div will extend the max-height of 350px.

This is how i have it right now:

```html
<div id="parent-left">
  <div id="top">
    Top-Content<br>
    Top-Content<br>
    Top-Content<br>
    Top-Content<br>
    Top-Content<br>
    Top-Content
  </div>
  <div id="bottom">
    Bottom-Content<br>Bottom-Content<br>Bottom-Content<br>Bottom-Content<br>
    Bottom-Content<br>Bottom-Content<br>Bottom-Content<br>Bottom-Content<br>
    Bottom-Content<br>Bottom-Content<br>Bottom-Content<br>Bottom-Content<br>
    Bottom-Content<br>Bottom-Content<br>Bottom-Content<br>Bottom-Content<br>
    Bottom-Content<br>Bottom-Content<br>Bottom-Content<br>Bottom-Content<br>
    Bottom-Content<br>Bottom-Content<br>Bottom-Content<br>Bottom-Content<br>
    Bottom-Content<br>Bottom-Content<br>Bottom-Content<br>Bottom-Content<br>
    Bottom-Content<br>Bottom-Content<br>Bottom-Content<br>Bottom-Content<br>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="parent-right">
  Other Div with actual height of 350px
</div>
```

```css
#parent-left {
  height: 350px;
  background: red;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}

#parent-right {
  height: 350px;
  background: red;
  width: 50%;
  float: right;
}

#top {
    background:#5ae;
}

#bottom {
  background:#ea5;
  height:100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Lps0t2ze/

As you can see, the Red Div (actual 350px height) is not the same height, since the parent-left div is bigger.

I know its possible when i define the heights myself (like here: http://jsfiddle.net/by96zof3/) but that would kill the variable-height of the divs.

So what i want is that the #parent-left div doesnt go over 350px, but also i dont have to define any heights inside.

I can use JS (& JQuery), but i would prefer a solution without it if possible.

Anyone got some ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`flex` is your friend, my friend.

```
#parent-left {
  height: 350px;
  background: red;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

Comment: thx, that did the trick. didnt even knew flex-direction: column is a thing